# Как оптимизировать код на PHP?

Tags: php, рефакторинг

Задача: Получить все пары [дружественных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) от 1 до 300. Нужно оптимизировать функцию `getAmicableNumbers()` так, чтобы она выполнялась быстрее и кушала меньше памяти. Данная функция производит обход всех чисел в указанном диапазоне и проверяет их на дружественность посредством функции `isAmicableNumbers()`.

```
function getAmicableNumbers($from, $to) {
  $amicableNumbers = [];

  for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
    for ($j = $from; $j <= $to; $j++) {
      if (isAmicableNumbers($i, $j)) {
        $amicableNumbers[] = array($i,$j);
      }
    }
  };
 
  return $amicableNumbers;
};
```

Comment: симметричные пары исключить надо.

Comment: isAmicableNumbers это какая-то данность? Потому что гораздо логичнее не делать вложенный цикл, а для числа вычислять потенциальное «дружественное число» и проверить действительно ли оно дружественное…

Comment: Ваш вопрос сводится к тому, как оптимизировать цикл в цикле, т.к. функцию проверки вы не даете. Тут  ни генераторы, не декартово множество вам не поможет, т.к. в основном вы нагрузку то и получите из-за некой компарации, которая происходит именно на каждой итерации, а сами циклы ваш код не особо замедлят. В теории, @AlexeyTen правильно вам подсказал, можно стараться предугадать набор дружественных чисел и проверять уже его (либо кол-во дружественных чисел в определенном диапозоне).